# UWP in Fullscreen Mode, KeyDown stops working with Keyboard Barcodescanner

Tags: c#, uwp, keydown

When i scan a Barcode with my scanner (for the PC the scanner is a Keyboard, it don't know that it is a Barcodescanner) sometimes in fullscreen mode the KeyDown Event isn't handled until i move my mouse a little bit.

as you can see:
[image]

it seems like the program is losing the focus at some point. when i try it without the fullscreen mode it works like it should.

[image]

i already used this 4 methodes to get the key, but all have the same behaviour:

```
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().CharacterReceived += MainPage_CharacterReceived;
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += MainPage_KeyDown; ;

Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;

Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
```

is that bug well known already and is there anything i could do, to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Perhaps storing the incoming text from the barcode scanner, and displaying it in the UI separately in different software modules would make your program independent of whether the window has focus or not, and would allow it to be ran in the background aswell.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue , But I think you could make the page `Focus` Programmatic when CoreWindow enter full screen mode. if you want to try, I will share my code for testing.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT i actually found this bug listed on the Visual Studio developercommunity Page (I don't have the link anymore).Anyways, it seems like it works fine on the client machines. At least we didn't had a problem with that in the last 3 months.

Edit: But it still happens when i debug my program with visual studio